# Set custom error handler for certain functions

Tags: php, error-handling

I am aware of the `set_error_handler` function.. But I am wondering if it's possible to set a custom error handler for certain user defined functions? Example.

```
  function ArrayToString ($Array){
    if (!is_array($Array)){
      trigger_error("Not Array", Not_Array); // I know this is invalid syntax but an example
    }
    return implode (" ",$Array);
  }
```

Then something like:

```
   set_handler_Not_Array(){
     //Format with some CSS
     echo "The Argument supplied within ".$errline." <br> Inside: ".$errfile." Is not a valid Array";
    exit;
   }
```

Is a solution like this possible? Or would I do I have to resort to the current error handling that is in use:

```
function Error_Handler($errno, $errstr,$error_file,$error_line)
    {
        $MySQLCheck = "mysql_connect()"; // String to search for 
        $MySQL = strpos($errstr, $MySQLCheck); // Looks inside the $errstr for the string $MySQLCheck
        if ($MySQL !== false) // if Contains the $MySQLCheck
        {
            unset($errstr); // Unsets the current error message (which usually states username@host 
            $errstr = "Can Not Connect To Database"; // Changes the error message to something thatdoes not give away username or host. 
        }
        $UndefinedIndex = "Undefined index:"; // String to search for 
        $Index = strpos($errstr, $UndefinedIndex); // Searches $errstr for the String listed above 
        if ($Index !== false) // If contains the $UndefinedIndex
        {
            $errstrbkup = $errstr; // Saves $errstr to another variable before the $errstr is changes 
            $str = str_replace("Undefined index:", "", $errstrbkup); // replaces "Undefined Index:" with nothing 
            $errstr = "A Button Does not Seem To Be Handled Correctly! <br> <b>Button Name:</b> $str ";  // Changes the $errstr to a new message 
        }
        $UndefinedIndex = "Undefined variable:"; // String to search for 
        $Variable = strpos($errstr, $UndefinedIndex); // Searches $errstr for the String listed above 
        if ($Variable !== false) // If contains the $UndefinedIndex
        {
            $errstrbkup = $errstr; // Saves $errstr to another variable before the $errstr is changes 
            $str = str_replace("Undefined variable:", "", $errstrbkup); // replaces "Undefined Index:" with nothing 
            $errstr = "A Variable Does Not Seem To Be Handled. Check $str";  // Changes the $errstr to a new message 
        }   
            $ErrorFile = str_replace("/home/u394942373/public_html/", "", $error_file); // Removes the /var/www from showing in the error
        // remove the full path up to the file root if detected

        echo 
            "Opps, It Seems An error Has Been Encountered <br>
            Technical Information Listed Below: <br>
            <br><br><br>
            <b>Error Message:</b> $errstr <br>
            <b>File Causing Error:</b> $ErrorFile<br>
            <b>Line:</b> $error_line <br>
            A Member Of The Technical Department Has Been Notified And Will Fix This Error When Available.
            ";
     die();
    }
    //set error handler
    set_error_handler("Error_Handler");
```

The reason for this, is because my line manager wishes to have a custom error handler for certain types of error messages... Or for every new error thrown would we still have the be modifying the current error handler

Comment: Have you seen [`this`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)? Do something like `throw new Exception('Not an array');`

Comment: Manager would rather not use a try/catch option